# preposition used with “autonomous”:  “of ” vs “from”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Two related questions here:

1. Is it proper to use the construct, “Administrative components are autonomous **of/from** the front-end components”?
2. If it is proper, which of these two prepositions works better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This word is best used in an absolute sense, i.e. without specifying what the autonomous entity would depend on if it weren't autonomous. If you need a contrast, use "independent of" ("of" is better than "from"), as Nicholas recommends.

The word "autonomous" comes from Greek *autos*, "own, self", and *nomos*, "law". It means "having one's own laws": the fact that you cannot easily add whatever is opposed to "one's own laws" to this phrase may serve to illustrate why "autonomous" is traditionally used without modifiers, or so I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Use *independent **of** / **from** the front-end components*

Or they are *autonomous **in respect to** the the front-end components*

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to say 'work independently of...' ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *autonomous* can be used like this at all. You would have to say "is autonomous relative to the front-end components" or "in relation to the front-end components".